# Salesforce trigger sequence

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex

I have two triggers on a object.

One is managed package which I could not see or amend the content inside the trigger.

One is design by me.

I want to run my own created trigger before the managed package trigger. Could I control the sequence of the execution of the trigger.

Because it now always run the managed package trigger first. I would like to run my trigger first. I have been think for a few days. All colleague in my company could not know how to achieve this goal. Without fixing this issue, I couldn't be able to continue my work. Please help me out.

Comment: The managed trigger runs before or after? Generally we have no control over the order, that's why it's a bad idea to have more than 1 trigger firing on same "before insert" for example. In really complex scenarios I even use http://www.embracingthecloud.com/2010/07/08/ASimpleTriggerTemplateForSalesforce.aspx. Have you tried contacting your package's author?

Answer (score 0):

In the system there is no way to control the sequence of calls triggers, I think this limitation of unsafe programming. Do you have access to the package trigger? This is a really bad approach to have several triggers on a one object, better solution is to have a single trigger that will invoke various handlers. Then, on handlers level you can manage sequence of this handlers..

For example, this is simple trigger, which is invoked on different events and calls different methods with various logic:

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (before insert, before update) {

    /* Before Update*/  
    if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isBefore){
         /*
         here you can invoke different methods of different classes
         (trigger handlers) in different sequences
         */
    }

    /* Before Insert*/
    if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isBefore){
        //on other events you can use it too
    }
}
}
```

In order to ensure that a handler can be invoked only after finishing of executing previous handler,  you can use the state variables whose values ​​will be changed at the end of handler, and you can check before calling other handlers. I hope this will help you in the future:)